# Batch file extract string part

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I have this window's batch command:

```
wmic process call create "notepad.exe" | find "ProcessId"
```

It returns this string

```
(spaces)  ProcessId = 13764;
```

And I need to store in a variable only the pid number (13764), how can I do?

Comment: here's where I've used the same thing: http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=5866#p5866

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('wmic process call create "notepad.exe" ^| find "ProcessId"') do (
   for %%b in (%%a) do set value=%%b
)
echo %value%
```

This method return the *last word* in the line, so it may be used also in other lines with variable number of words at beginning.

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=;= " %%P in ('wmic process call create "notepad.exe" ^| find "ProcessId"') do echo %%P
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
echo %strContent:~6, -1%
```

Comment: this is not pretty reliable .The length of the PID number could vary.Better to be splitted with `FOR /F` or to use two substitutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f  "tokens=3 delims=;=" %%a in ("(spaces)  ProcessId = 13764;") do set value=%%c
echo %value%
```